# Android linear layouts aligning to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Been tearing my hair out all day over this

I am trying to have two linear layouts at the bottom of the screen, each will have a few bottoms. I want one linear layout to the right and one to the left

So far I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT WILL GO HERE -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="£12.50" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate1 **** " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which produces

[image: first attempt]
Now I try and add the second layout on the left hand side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT WILL GO HERE -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="£12.50" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate1 **** " />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="£12.50" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate1 **** " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which produces:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Both of your child linear layouts have `android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, which won't work. If you want to split the space evenly look into using *layout_weight*.

Comment: that worked! I used android:layout_weight="1" Can you answer the question so I can mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your child linear layouts have

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

This won't work. If you want to split the space evenly look into using `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 1):

You can to make something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT WILL GO HERE -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

       <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="£12.50" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rate1 **** " />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="£13.50" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rate2 **** " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either use the android:layout_weight attribute for your layouts so that you can specify how much of the screen is taken up by each LinearLayout ViewGroup or else as the comment above specifies, you need to alter the layouts so that they both aren't trying to fill up the parent ViewGroup.  You can set it to wrap_content, which might not look so nice because the screen could have voids not filled by any ViewGroup